# Proper Date Formatting for Cookies

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, cookies, session-cookies

So I am trying to do what I think is the impossible. I want to destroy all session cookies on browser or tab close, so I came up with a solution, I am just having small issues with JavaScript formatting. This does have to be time based, as when the next page reloads, it will put the timer for expiration for a year, so that other pages on my site don't delete the cookies as well. So until they navigate away from the site or close the tab, the cookie wont expire.

So The JavaScript starts like this:

```
var today = new Date(); 
today.setSeconds(today.getSeconds() + 5);

alert(today);



window.onunload = function(){
   document.cookie = 'PHPSESSID=; expires=' + today;
   };
```

So When I run this, it does not recognize the today variable, or I am not formatting today correctly.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Well, I think I am going to try another method, this doesn't seem to be working out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decided to destroy the session cookies with a small script.

This is what I came up with.

```
window.onunload = function(){
  var today = new Date();
  today.setSeconds(today.getSeconds() + 2);
  var today1= today.toUTCString()



  document.cookie =
      'PHPSESSID=<?php echo $sesid; ?>; expires='+ today1 +'; path=/'
      alert(document.cookie);
  };
```

So This will set the destroy to 2 seconds, but if you navigate to any other page on my site, it will run this first.

```
var today2 = new Date();
today2.setSeconds(today2.getSeconds() + 10000);
var today3= today2.toUTCString()

document.cookie =
  'PHPSESSID=<?php echo $sesid; ?>; expires='+ today3 +'; path=/';
```

This allows the session to be destroyed anytime you navigate away from the page.

Answer (score 1):

The `today` variable is out of scope. You need to create it in the unload, or pass it in the function().

```
window.onunload = function(today){
   document.cookie = 'PHPSESSID=; expires=' + today.getTime();
   };
```

OR

```
    window.onunload = function(){
       var today = new Date(); 
       today.setSeconds(today.getSeconds() + 5);

       document.cookie = 'PHPSESSID=; expires=' + today.getTime();
       };
```

Comment: Oh. DERP! I will try this.

Comment: This still does not work for this script. Thank you for the correction though.

Comment: @KevinWeber Does `alert` outputs the value of `today`?

Comment: you probably want today.getTime() by the way

Comment: No, It does not alert, but it does when it is outside of the function.

Comment: Does changing "today.getTime()" to "today.toUTCString()" do anything?